# javafx using objects from MainController or other Controllers in proper Controller class

Tags: java, javafx, controller, fxml

I have following code:

```
package pl.javastart.youtufy.controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ConnectionErrorController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label infoLabel;

    @FXML
    private Button tryButton;

    @FXML
    private Button exitButton;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        MainController mc = new MainController();

        infoLabel.setText("Connection lost, please try again");
        tryButton.setText("try again");
        exitButton.setText("exit");

        tryButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                WebEngine webEngine = mc.getContentPaneController().getVideoWebView().getEngine(); // 1
                ToggleButton playButton = mc.getControlPaneController().getPlayButton(); // 2
                Node source = (Node) event.getSource();
                Stage stage = (Stage) source.getScene().getWindow();
                if (mc.testInet()) {
                    stage.close();
                    mc.play(webEngine, playButton);
                } else {
                    stage.close();
                    MainController.exist = false;
                }
            }
        });

        exitButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                Platform.exit();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am trying to use WebEngine and ToggleButton Objects from controllers in MainController (I generated getters and setters to them in MainController):

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private ContentPaneController contentPaneController;

@FXML
private ControlPaneController controlPaneController;

@FXML
private MenuPaneController menuPaneController;

@FXML
private SearchPaneController searchPaneController;

private Youtube youtubeInstance;

public static boolean exist = false;

public ControlPaneController getControlPaneController() {
    return controlPaneController;
}

public void setControlPaneController(ControlPaneController controlPaneController) {
    this.controlPaneController = controlPaneController;
}

public ContentPaneController getContentPaneController() {
    return contentPaneController;
}

public void setContentPaneController(ContentPaneController contentPaneController) {
    this.contentPaneController = contentPaneController;
}
```

But its still returns NullPointerException. I had same problem, when I tried simply make references to the controllers in ConnectionErrorController. How to refer to the ToggleButton i WebEngine Objects from controllers in ConnectionErrorController properly?
Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a controller instance "by hand" with

```
MainController mc = new MainController();
```

`@FXML`-annotated fields are initialized by the `FXMLLoader` when it creates the controller for you as part of the process of loading the FXML file. Since the controller you created is not the controller instance created by the `FXMLLoader`, its `@FXML`-annotated fields are uninitialized (i.e. they are null), and hence you get a null pointer exception.

You can get a reference to the controller created by the `FXMLLoader` by calling `getController()` on the `FXMLLoader` instance after calling `load()`.

If you want one controller to communicate with another, then pass the reference to one controller to the other controller, by defining appropriate methods in the second controller:

```
public class ConnectionErrorController implements Initializable {

    private MainController mainController ;

    public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController ;
    }

    // ...

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        infoLabel.setText("Connection lost, please try again");
        tryButton.setText("try again");
        exitButton.setText("exit");

        tryButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                WebEngine webEngine = mainController.getContentPaneController().getVideoWebView().getEngine(); // 1
                ToggleButton playButton = mainController.getControlPaneController().getPlayButton(); // 2
                if (mainController.testInet()) {
                    mainController.play(webEngine, playButton);
                } else {
                    // obviously you can now do something better than the "public static field hack" here:
                    MainController.exist = false;
                }
                tryButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();
            }
        });

        // ...
    }
}
```

Assuming you are loading the second fxml file in a method in `MainController`, you can then just do something like:

```
public class MainController {

    // ...

    public void showConnectionErrorWindow(String fileName) {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/ConnectionError.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        ConnectionErrorController connectionErrorController = loader.getController();
        connectionErrorController.setMainController(this);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        // etc...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note that there are much more elegant ways of solving this problem, such as passing the `ConnectionErrorController` a callback function (in the form of a lambda expression) to process the call to `play(...)`, which avoid the tight coupling between the `ConnectionErrorController` and the `MainController`. However, as you seem to be new to Java, this simpler approach might be more suitable.

See [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963) for more information on passing values to controllers.