# How to update table cells with new information using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, cell

Whenever I click a row, I want to update the table with new information. For some reason when I click it is not doing anything and errors out. Any idea why I can't do this?

```
public HierarchyItemTreeCellCallback(TreeView<Requirement> treeView, DataModel dataModelIn)
{
    super();
    treeViewParent = treeView;
    dataModel = dataModelIn;
  }

  @Override
    public TreeCell<Requirement> call(TreeView<Requirement> param)
    {
    TreeCell<Requirement> cell = new HierarchyItemTreeCell();
    cell.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
    {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
            {
                HierarchyTabController hierarchyTabController = new HierarchyTabController(dataModel);
                Requirement req1 = new Requirement("ID", "21", 1, REQUIREMENT_TYPE.SOFTWARE);
                hierarchyTabController.updateTableRow(req1);
            }
    });
    return cell;
  }
```

Here is the controller logic:

```
public void updateTableRow(Requirement r)
{
    REQUIREMENT_TYPE reqType = REQUIREMENT_TYPE.SOFTWARE;
    Requirement req1 = new Requirement("ID", "21", 1, reqType);
    ObservableList<Requirement> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(req1);
    name.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
    description.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("description"));
    tableView.getItems().setAll(list);
    tableView.setItems(list);
}
```

This works whenever I do not call the updateTableRow function from the MouseEvent. However, it is not working when I try to call the controller and update the values from the MouseEvent. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Table cell? or Tree cell?

Comment: Tree Cell @James_D

Comment: Oh yeah... @fabian is as fed up with this question as I am. "I created a new instance of the controller class. Why are the fields injected by the `FXMLLoader` null?"

Comment: Hmmm. I guess I cannot create a new instance of the controller class? What is the work around then? How can I update the new values? @James_D

Comment: Well you can, obviously, create a new instance of the controller class, but it's pretty useless, as you presumably want to call `updateTableRow(...)` on the actual controller, not some arbitrary other instance of the same class. You can get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` when you actually load the FXML.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36482632/javafx-using-objects-from-maincontroller-or-other-controllers-in-proper-controll or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457811/javafx-how-to-get-instance-of-the-controller-object or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class or...